# How can I generate a list of all possible permutations of several letters?

Tags: python, permutation, alphabetical

So I am making a word generator that takes several inputted letters, puts them in all possible positions, and matches them with a document to find words. If I am approaching this wrong please tell me! If not how can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Note that, for a string `len(s) == n`, the number of permutations is `n!`; this gets big pretty fast (there are 3,628,800 permutations of my user name, for example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to generate all permutations of a given list of letters, use the itertools module.

```
import itertools 
for word in itertools.permutations( list_of_letters ):
   print ''.join(word)
```

Comment: If I have 7 letters in the list will this also generate permutaions of 6 letter words? Or 5? Or 4? ect.

Comment: no, only permutations of 7 letters, but itertools for sure does what you want, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: @codeman99 You can, just pass length that you want as second argument. `itertools.permutations( list_of_letters, length )`[docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own function (:

```
def permutation(head, tail=''):
    if len(head) == 0: 
        print tail
    else:
        for i in range(len(head)):
            permutation(head[0:i] + head[i + 1:], tail + head[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be faster to run it in reverse: index your document, and for each word, see if it is a subset of your list of letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
def allpermutationsOfString(words):
  if len(words) == 1:
    return [words]
  result = []
  for index, letter in enumerate(words):
    wordWithoutLetter = words[:index] + words[index+1:]
    result = result + [letter + word for word in allpermutationsOfString(wordWithoutLetter)]
  return result

print allpermutationsOfString("watup") #will print all permutations of watup
```

Here's another way to implement the algorithm.